# Spaces: Rename Desktops

Tags: spaces

Is it possible to dynamically rename spaces, (*as if I was renaming a folder or file*),
so I can write small descriptions of the ongoing project contained in each?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to rename spaces using an app called [Spaces Renamer](https://github.com/dado3212/spaces-renamer). It is available on GitHub for free.

[image]
  *The compressed view after pressing F3*


  [image]
  *The expanded view after hovering*


  [image]
  *The interface for renaming the spaces*

*Image sources: [the GitHub page](https://github.com/dado3212/spaces-renamer)*

Please note that to use it you have to disable System Integrity Protection to use this tool. You'll need to download MacForge to use it. All of the installation instructions are on the GitHub page.

It does not work for the time being on macOS macOS Big Sur due to increased system protections there. Only time will tell if it will be supported there. However, it works perfectly fine on macOS Catalina.